# dataframe column's aggregate based on simple majority

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `dataframe` from my model's prediction similar to the one below:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'trip-id': [8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4],
 'segment-id': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,5,5,5,5,5],
 'true_label': [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
 'prediction': [3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 4, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2]})

df
 trip-id    segment-id  true_label  prediction
0   8           1          3            3
1   8           1          3            3
2   8           1          3            3
3   8           1          3            1
4   8           1          3            2
5   8           1          3            4
6   8           1          3            0
7   8           1          3            0
8   4           0          3            3
9   4           0          3            3
10  4           0          3            3
11  4           0          3            0
12  4           0          3            1
13  4           0          3            2
14  4           5          3            3
15  4           5          3            3
16  4           5          3            1
17  4           5          3            1
18  4           5          3            2
19  4           5          3            2
```

In the given sample are predictions and true label  for the instances `[0,1,..4]` of trips' segments.

I would like to generate a summary of segment's predictions based on simple majority.

- to consider as segment's predicted value, the value of that predicted instance `[0,1,..4]` of the segment having simple majority.
- where there's a tie for the majority predicted instances, the value matching the `true_label` is considered the segment's prediction.
- if there's a tie of majority, and none of the instances in the tie matches the `true_label`, then from those in the tie, the instance coming first in the `df` is regarded the segment's predicted value.

Currently I can do this:

```py
segments_summary = (
     df['true_label'].eq(df['prediction'])
       .groupby([df['true_label'],df['trip-id'], df['segment-id']]).mean()
       .ge(0.5)
       .groupby(level='true_label').agg(['size','sum'])
       .rename(columns={'size':'total-segments','sum':'correctly-predicted'})\
       .assign(recall = lambda x: round(x['correctly-predicted']/x['total-segments'], 2))
       .reindex(range(5), fill_value='-')
       .reset_index())
```

Which produces:

```py
segments_summary
  true_label    total-segments  correctly-predicted recall
0    0              -                   -             -
1    1              -                   -             -
2    2              -                   -             -
3    3              3                   1           0.33
4    4              -                   -             -
```

But this is not exactly what I wanted. Going by the conditions I above, all the 3 segments should have been predicted correctly.

- `trip 8, segment 1`: `3` has the simple majority, so that segment should considered as predicted `3`
- `trip 4, segment 0`: `3` has simple majority, that segment is predicted as `3`.
- `trip 4, segment 5`: is s tie, so the prediction matching `true_label`  should be the segment's prediction -> `3`.

Expected result:

```py
  true_label    total-segments  correctly-predicted recall
0    0              -                   -             -
1    1              -                   -             -
2    2              -                   -             -
3    3              3                   3            1.0
4    4              -                   -             -
```

Comment: use `pd.Series.mode` in aggregation instead of average of correct predictions

Comment: For the expected result, you don't really need the third condition where there's tie and no match for correct prediction.

Comment: @QuangHoang oh yes, I am giving account of might be the case if it happens, mayb someone would ask.

Comment: @Marat  I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

I would use:

```
out = (df
   # get the top prediction
   .value_counts(sort=False).reset_index(name='count')
   .assign(flag=lambda d: d['true_label'].eq(d['prediction']))
   .sort_values(by=['trip-id', 'segment-id', 'count', 'flag'],
                ascending=[True, True, False, False],
                kind='stable'
               )
   .groupby(['trip-id', 'segment-id']).first()
   # check if correctly predicted
   .assign(**{'correctly-predicted': lambda d: d['true_label'].eq(d['prediction'])})
   # aggregate per prediction
   .groupby('prediction')
   .agg(**{'total-segments': ('prediction', 'count'),
           'correctly-predicted': ('correctly-predicted', 'sum')
          })
   .assign(**{'recall': lambda d: d['correctly-predicted'].div(d['total-segments'])})
   .reindex(range(5), fill_value='-')
   .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
   prediction total-segments correctly-predicted recall
0           0              -                   -      -
1           1              -                   -      -
2           2              -                   -      -
3           3              3                   3    1.0
4           4              -                   -      -
```